# SQLAlchemy create database and then change owner

Tags: python, postgresql, orm, sqlalchemy

im experimenting with and Sqlachemy and ORM, and im trying to translate raw sql to ORM structure.
my problem is with setting ownship

raw sql file will look like this:

```
CREATE DATABASE mydb WITH ENCODING='UTF8' OWNER otheruser;

CREATE TABLE mytable
(
    id VARCHAR NOT NULL UNIQUE,
    data VARCHAR NOT NULL,
    PRIMARY KEY (id)
);
ALTER TABLE mytable OWNER TO otheruser;
```

to apply, i just run:

```
psql -U postgres -r raw_sql_file.sql
```

my module looks like this:

```
from sqlalchemy_utils import database_exists, create_database

class DataProvider(object):
    def __init__(self):

        engine = create_engine(
            "postgresql+psycopg2://postgres:@localhost/mydb")

        if not database_exists(engine.url):
            create_database(engine.url)

        Base.metadata.create_all(engine)
        self.session = sessionmaker(bind=engine)()



class MyTable(Base):
    __tablename__ = 'mytable'
    id = Column(String, primary_key=True)
    data = Column(String, nullable=False)
```

when i initiate DataProvider class, database is created from scratch if it doesn't exists.

my problem is that the database is owned by `postgres` user. i cant find a good way to change database and table township to a different one.

what am i missing?

Comment: Connect to the database using `otheruser` instead of `postgres` since the otheruser is already a database owner.

Comment: @AnttiHaapala that will work, but what if i want to use postgres user to create my database and then give just read permissions to another user.
can i do it from the code?

Comment: ... and furthermore, for any serious database creation you should consider using the `alembic` migration tool instead.

Comment: @AnttiHaapala that is exactly what im doing :) moving raw sql to ORM and implementing migration workflow with alembic

Comment: I checked the docs and one way to do it would've been if `__table_args__` supported owner, but alas no.

Comment: You want the user `postgres` to own the tables but want to query using a normal user? Just set the owner to `postgres`, create the database/tables, then reconnect using the other user.

Comment: @univerio thanks, that might be a good solution for me.